# create and aggregate variable for time/ .5hz in r

Tags: r, merge, aggregate, reshape

I'm trying to create a new variable for time in seconds (as measured in 0.5hz, i.e. corresponding to 2 seconds) within trials depending on the variables time as measured in the experiment.
Each trial should start with 0 then increase in steps of 2 seconds.

My data looks like this:

```
df_now <- data.frame(
  time = 68.15:86,
  trial_no = (c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4")), 
  value = rnorm(18, 0, 3)
  )
```

and should ideally look something like this

```
df_tobe <- data.frame(
  time = 68.15:86,
  trial_no = (c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4")),
  value = rnorm(18, 0, 3),
  time.5hz = (c("0", "2", "2", "4", "4", "0", "2", "2", "0", "2","2", "4", "0", "2", "2", "4", "4", "6")), 
  value_mean_5hz = 'mean_value_per5hz'
)
```

(sorry for the crappy code)

In my data, much more decimals for time are involved, and time is not measured consistently (since it was only saved when a button was pressed).

Does anyone know what I could do?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you describe more about how the `time.5hz` values should be calculated? I don't understand the pattern.

Comment: sorry, time.5hz should basically be equal to, or summarise, 2seconds.

Comment: because it is dependent on the variable time. starting from 0 for each trial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
df_now %>% 
  group_by(trial_no) %>% 
  mutate(time.5hz = ceiling((time - min(time))/2)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 18 × 4
    time trial_no  value time.5hz
   <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>    <dbl>
 1  68.2 1         4.82         0
 2  69.2 1         2.61         1
 3  70.2 1         6.72         1
 4  71.2 1         2.46         2
 5  72.2 1         0.160        2
 6  73.2 2        -3.82         0
 7  74.2 2        -2.29         1
 8  75.2 2        -5.55         1
 9  76.2 3        -2.33         0
10  77.2 3         0.330        1
11  78.2 3         3.46         1
12  79.2 3        -2.36         2
13  80.2 4         0.501        0
14  81.2 4        -4.16         1
15  82.2 4        -1.73         1
16  83.2 4         1.05         2
17  84.2 4        -0.991        2
18  85.2 4         1.38         3
```

Comment: cool thank you! but I didn't explain it well, time.5hz should have been values in steps of two (2,4,6,8..). also edited above. is there any way to do that, too?
thank you so much!!

Comment: Add `2 * ` before `ceiling`.